# Import updated variable from module

Tags: python, python-import

I am having problems importing a variable from a module after updating it. I am working with 3 files: the first is the 'main' file and launches the functions, the second is the 'setup' and contains the variable and the function which modifies it, the third is the 'help' file which uses the variable. The problem is, when I launch the 'main' file and then the function from the 'setup' to modify the variable, everything works fine. But when I launch the 'help' file, it uses the non-updated variable, and I cannot understand why.

main.py:

```
from colorama import init
from termcolor import colored
import subprocess
import check_functions_and_setup
init()  # starts colorama
while True:
    color = check_functions_and_setup.color_main
    command = raw_input(colored("Insert function: \n >> ", color))
    if (command == "help") or (command == "Help"):
        process = subprocess.call('start /wait python help_function.py', shell=True)
    elif command == "change color help":
        # updates the color in the setup file
        check_functions_and_setup.color_help = check_functions_and_setup.change_color_help(check_functions_and_setup.color_list, check_functions_and_setup.color_help, color)
```

setup:

```
color_help = "cyan"
color_list = ["grey", "red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "magenta", "cyan", "white"]
def change_color_help(color_list, color_help, color):
    input_color = raw_input(colored("Insert new color: \n >> ", color))
    if input_color in color_list:
        return input_color
    else:
        print colored("Invalid color", color)
        return color_help
```

help:

```
from colorama import init
from termcolor import colored
import check_functions_and_setup
init()  # starts colorama
print colored("WELCOME IN THE HELP PROGRAM!", check_functions_and_setup.color_help)
```

the last line is the not-working one; in fact, even if I succesfully change the help_color from the function the line is printed in the same color of the original color_help variable.

Comment: How do you expect this to work? You don't change `color_help` anywhere in your `help.py` script as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running the help code via `subprocess`. That child process won't share memory with the parent process where `main` is running (and where you've changed the color). Rather than running the help code as a separate process, just have the `main` module `import` the help module and call whatever functionality you need.

Here is a simplified version of your code:

```
# main.py

import settings
from help import show_color

while True:
    action = raw_input('Action: ')
    if action == '':
        break
    elif action == 'help':
        show_color()
    else:
        settings.set_color()

# settings.py

color = 'cyan'

def set_color():
    global color
    color = raw_input('Enter new color: ')

# help.py

import settings

def show_color():
    print 'help.py: ', settings.color
```

Note that your design -- where you are relying on changing the value of a global variable within a module -- is fairly awkward and rigid. There are almost certainly better ways to handle such color changes.

Comment: The only problem is that I wanted the help module to run on another terminal which is opened when I call the help function. I am quite new in the python language. The thing I don't understand is why the help module doesn't read the variable in the setup module even if I call it correctly.

Comment: @GiampoOrigin Because you are running the main and help modules in different processes. Processes do not share memory space. This is not a Python issue; it's the way computers work. If you want two processes to share information like that, you'll need a very different approach.

Comment: Wow, I think I finally understood. Thanks a lot